# How many epoch or blocks do I need to wait to be a Validator?

Tags: go-ethereum, validators, prysm

I made my own testnet at the moment, I made some keys and wallet for Validators and also deposit to contract.

But when I start the validator(prysm) they just keep showing "INFO validator: Valdating for public key publicKey=0x~".

So How many epoch or blocks do I need to wait to see the status changed.

This is my log text(some of them is What I add to code to check the progress) and config.yml file

**Ubuntu Terminal**

```
hun@kpnode3:~/ether-edit$ ./validator --wallet-dir=validator_keys --suggested-fee-recipient=0xd088a8031953a777b065976b7cc3a0d381c097cc --datadir validatordata --beacon-rpc-provider 127.0.0.1:4000 --kpuniverse --accept-terms-of-use
[2024-02-07 11:44:25]  WARN flags: Running on the KPUniverse Beacon Chain Testnet
initializeFromCLI asking for wallet
Wallet password: 
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO node: Opened validator wallet keymanager-kind=direct wallet=/home/hun/ether-edit/validator_keys/direct
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO node: Checking DB databasePath=validatordata
Adding optimizations for validator slashing protection 100% [================================================]  [0s:0s]
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  WARN node: Fee recipient 0xd088a8031953a777b065976b7cc3a0d381c097cc is not a checksum Ethereum address. The checksummed address is 0xd088a8031953a777B065976B7Cc3A0D381c097cc and will be used as the fee recipient. We recommend using a mixed-case address (checksum) to prevent spelling mistakes in your fee recipient Ethereum address
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  WARN validator: You are using an insecure gRPC connection. If you are running your beacon node and validator on the same machines, you can ignore this message. If you want to know how to enable secure connections, see: https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/prysm-usage/secure-grpc
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO node: Starting validator node version=Prysm/Unknown/Local build. Built at: Moments ago
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO validator: Syncing with beacon node to align on chain genesis info
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO validator: Beacon chain started genesisTime=2024-02-07 06:46:37 +0000 UTC
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO validator: Validating for public key publicKey=0x8afbc6426659
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO validator: Validating for public key publicKey=0x801338c87c27
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO validator: Validating for public key publicKey=0xa7b18597de54
[2024-02-07 11:44:31]  INFO validator: Validating for public key publicKey=0xaf4076db6858
no active key 루프
status.publicKey :  [138 251 198 66 102 89 89 160 27 84 247 87 14 192 24 40 143 126 30 232 82 191 133 143 35 113 51 98 185 41 183 132 76 49 225 252 111 124 37 143 253 22 9 173 198 242 106 52]
status.status.Status.String() :  DEPOSITED
status.status.PositionInActivationQueue :  0
status.publicKey :  [128 19 56 200 124 39 31 27 168 120 80 240 22 31 254 50 220 149 214 87 103 182 15 222 6 117 180 233 45 68 233 139 166 246 134 242 185 166 245 69 182 71 40 212 70 210 83 158]
status.status.Status.String() :  DEPOSITED
status.status.PositionInActivationQueue :  0
status.publicKey :  [167 177 133 151 222 84 88 61 129 86 151 32 76 23 18 212 123 217 194 149 219 29 13 67 108 72 41 53 229 22 169 225 234 209 146 251 244 106 124 156 1 2 242 128 39 53 119 162]
status.status.Status.String() :  DEPOSITED
status.status.PositionInActivationQueue :  0
status.publicKey :  [175 64 118 219 104 88 71 203 166 88 9 176 190 175 121 94 3 36 8 198 34 245 233 179 174 56 35 175 178 229 231 141 73 235 160 17 240 253 153 179 158 243 190 180 134 0 29 25]
status.status.Status.String() :  DEPOSITED
status.status.PositionInActivationQueue :  0
```

**config.yml**

```
CONFIG_NAME: interop
PRESET_BASE: interop

# Genesis
GENESIS_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000089

# Altair
ALTAIR_FORK_EPOCH: 0
ALTAIR_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000090

# Merge
BELLATRIX_FORK_EPOCH: 0
BELLATRIX_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000091
TERMINAL_TOTAL_DIFFICULTY: 0

# Capella
CAPELLA_FORK_EPOCH: 0
CAPELLA_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000092
MAX_WITHDRAWALS_PER_PAYLOAD: 16

DENEB_FORK_VERSION: 0x20000093

# Time parameters
SECONDS_PER_SLOT: 12
SLOTS_PER_EPOCH: 6

# Deposit contract
DEPOSIT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: 0x4242424242424242424242424242424242424242
```